# GetElementsByName geckofx

Tags: c#, html, getelementbyid, gecko, geckofx

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        geckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += ((se, ea) =>
        {
            TextBox email = (TextBox)sender;
            string emailText = email.Text;

            var emailField = new Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").DomObject);
            emailField.Value = emailText;
        });
        geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("instagram.com");
    }
```

focus at this one

```
var emailField = new Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").DomObject);
                emailField.Value = emailText;
```

i got many error with this, but when i try to change `GetElementsByTagName` to `GetHtmlElementById`, its works. but i need get elemnt by name, because instagram using `name=""` not `id=""`

Comment: Have you tried `GetElementsByName` ?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten this is the error message: Error 1 'Gecko.GeckoElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'DomObject' and no extension method 'DomObject' accepting a first argument of type 'Gecko.GeckoElementCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Underground\C#\IG Account Creator\IG Account Creator\Form1.cs 27 119 IG Account Creator

Comment: Note that `GetElementsByTagName` returns a collection, not just a single object (`Elements` is plural), so you likely need to choose the `Element` that you want before the `DomObject` extension method will be available.

Comment: I think @Ofir is on the right track, `GetElementsByName("fred")` returns a collection of HTML elements with the _name_ **attribute** that equal "fred" 'GetElementsByTagName("fred")` returns a collection of HTML elements of **type** "fred". If you have more than 1 element with the same **name** value, you will need to specify which one it is; or, rename accordingly.

Comment: @AdamV how about if i just wanna get by name, not tagname?

Comment: @MadMyche can you give me an example?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: Same thing - if you use `GetElementsByX`, even if there's only one, you need to select that one out of the collection (e.g., `GetElementsByName("abc")[0].DomObject` or `GetElementsByName("abc").First().DomObject`).

Comment: (Note that both the lines above will blow up if `GetElementsByName` returns an empty collection. Add error handling as necessary.)

Comment: @AdamV Very thanks dude this works

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to invoke `new GeckoInputElement` you can do a cast (see below).

You can use this code to get a collection of GeckoElements with a name attribute `name="nameOfMyElement"`.

Notice this is not the tag name.

```
var allElementsWithSpecifiedName  = this.Browser.Document.GetElementsByName("nameOfMyElement");
```

Now, since names are not unique, you are getting a collection.

You can then make a Linq query to get `FirstOrDefault();`, or access by index.

```
GeckoInputElement inputEle = allElementsWithSpecifiedName .FirstOrDefault() as GeckoInputElement;
```

If you are getting too many, then I suggest narrowing the search by first finding a parent element of the input and only then accessing by name.

For example:

```
var loginForm = this.Browser.Document.GetElementById("loginForm") as GeckoHtmlElement;
            var elements = loginForm.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            GeckoInputElement inputEle = elements.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.LocalName == "nameOfMyElement") as GeckoInputElement;
```